# Send base64 string as image to the client

Tags: image, web-services, rest, playframework, playframework-2.0

I managed to save an image as a base64 encoded string in my database, but I was wondering how tu serve the base64 string in a way that it is interpreted as an image on the client side.

i made a WS that returns the string like this :

```
return ok(myBase64String).as("image/jpeg")
```

but the image cannot be displayed in the browser.

if I decode the string and then send the byte array the image is displayed, now what i dont understand is why do I have to decode my already encoded image in order to display it in the client??

```
byte [] test =  Base64.decodeBase64(event.getPhoto());
                return ok(test).as("image/jpeg");
```

this works but why do I have to decode my base 64 string??

anyone have an idea?
thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Base64, you need to use the [data uri scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme):

```
<img src="data:image/png;<base64>" />
```

Otherwise you have to pass in a path to a binary representation. That's what the Assets controller does, serving a file as binary.

Comment: i retrieve the data from a webservice, will i profit from the browsers image caching?? with this?

Comment: How do you do it? If it is rendered server-side, only the HTML is cached.